# Error while installing django in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip, installation

I'm trying to install Django in ubuntu 18.04 in a virtual environment using command 'pip install Django' but it gives many errors as shown in the [screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJHWk.png)

One of the errors is :
"Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sagar/Documents/glug_aud/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
    yield

Comment: Please post the complete error message as text

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a socket timeout. This could be because of poor internet connectivity.

Comment: PyPI doesn't distinguish case. `pip install Django` and `pip install django` are completely equivalent.

Comment: @phd You are absolutely right. my bad ! edited my answer.